# Как вычислить площадь треугольника по двум сторонам и углу между ними?

Tags: javascript

Как вычислить площадь треугольника по двум сторонам и углу между ними?

```
S=absiny
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const a = 3             // Сторона a
const b = 4             // Сторона b
const y = Math.PI / 2   // Угол y в радианах

const S = a * b  * Math.sin(y) / 2  // Вычисление по формуле

console.log(S)  // Вывод в консоль
```